# Get rid of [untagged] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Recently I have come across the [untagged](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag. Why do we have this tag? Isn't the point of tags to keep the site organized?

Currently, there are only 2 questions with this tag. It shouldn't be to hard to just get rid of it, and find better tags to fit (in fact, it'll take like 5 minutes).

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tag that appears automatically when tags disappear. We recently burninated [best-practices](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practices), I think the one question remaining is probably leftover from that.

Another way for [untagged](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) to appear is when questions are migrated here and we don't have any of their original tags (just found out a minute ago).

By all means replace [untagged](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) with more sensible tags.